# Wrong result from IsNumeric() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, isnumeric

I have a function in VB.NET that loops through values and attempts to convert it to a decimal if `IsNumeric` is True,

```
Dim Value As String

If IsNumeric(Value) = True Then
    Rate = CType(Value, Decimal)  <--- bombing here
End If
```

I've found that when the function receives the value 603E43 `IsNumeric` evaluates to True for some reason and then bombs on the conversion. Why would `IsNumeric` be true in this case?

Comment: Because `603E43` is a semi-standard numerical representation of a floating point value, in particular: `603*10^43`. I have no idea how `CType` works (as I don't use VB.NET ;-), but in C# I'd might use `decimal.TryParse`. `IsNumeric` is likely more related to the SQL Server "numeric" rules, which also include leading dollar signs, etc. I can't seem to find any official "full" rules.

Comment: what do you mean by bombing ? what is the error message/exception ?

Comment: Perhaps see this [VB6 SO question about IsNumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470041/vb6-can-isnumeric-be-wrong) ... I am assuming VB.NET's IsNumeric is a good clone ;-)

Comment: @pst, Ah that sounds correct. Many thanks for the info.

Comment: On another point you dont need the `= True` part. Just say `If IsNumeric(Value) Then ...`

Comment: Dim x As Double
 Dim y As String = "1e3"
 If IsNumeric(y) Then x = CDbl(y) results in x=1000

Answer (score 10):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329488

IsNumeric returns true if it can be converted to a *double* which is true for 603E43 
The value is however larger than what a decimal can hold

You could use the Decimal.TryParse funcion as a working alternative. See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx

Comment: Personally, I've dumped using `IsNumeric` in favour of `<type>.TryParse` in all circumstances.  It's far more robust.

Comment: Ahh +1. This got me. I was about to say: "but a decimal is a wider type" because the *size* of decimal value is twice that of a double (128 vs 64 bits) -- yet the *range* is far less (while the *precision* is much higher). The *range* of decimal is +/- 10^28 while a double is +/- 10^308 (give or take).