# Is There any way to check data for its Data type in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, types

I want to check Data in all excel sheet column to ensure that data is as per its specified data type.

Like in a numeric column there should not be char value.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other post, Excel has some built in functions which allow you to test data in a field. This works great for the front end. It should also be noted that the datatypes available in the front end Excel are not the same datatypes available in the backend VBA (they are similar but different).

Datatypes in VBA in the backend can be trickier than other languages for two reasons: 1) The Variant datatype (which is a nondescript datatype) and 2) VBA doesn't by default require you to specify the datatype of a variable (it will try and guess what you meant unless you use the **Option Explicit** command).

Check out the following articles on available VBA datatypes and converting between them:

- [Data Type Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)
- [Type Conversions in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcb26cc8.aspx)
- [Variant Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the same functions as you would in Visual Basic. isdate, isnumeric, etc.  Make sure you test your data some.  Some of the data type checker functions are not fool-proof, especially isnumeric.  Here is one related thread to that [Wrong result from IsNumeric() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770117/wrong-result-from-isnumeric-in-vb-net)

There are many more out there if you search.